# How 'Input/Output' ports are mapped into memory?

Tags: memory, io

I have been trying to understand I/O ports and their mappings with the memory & I/O address space. I read about 'Memory Mapped I/O' and was wondering how this is accomplished by OS/Hardware. Does OS/Hardware uses some kind of table to map address specified in the instruction to respective port ?

Answer (score 1):

Implementations differ in many ways. But the basic idea is that when a read or write occurs for a memory address, the microprocessor outputs the address on its bus. Hardware (called an 'address decoder') detects that the address is for a particular memory-mapped I/O device and enables that device as the target of the operation.

Typically, the OS doesn't do anything special. On some platforms, the BIOS or operating system may have to configure certain parameters for the hardware to work properly.

For example, the range may have to be set as uncacheable to prevent the caching logic from reordering operations to devices that care about the order in which things happen. (Imagine if one write tells the hardware what operation to do and another write tells the hardware to start. Reordering those could be disastrous.)

On some platforms, the operating system or BIOS may have to set certain memory-mapped I/O ranges as 'slow' by adding wait states. This is because the hardware that's the target of the operation may not be as fast as the system memory is.

Some devices may allow the operating system to choose where in memory to map the device. This is typical of newer plug-and-play devices on the PC platform.

In some devices, such as microcontrollers, this is all done entirely inside a single chip. A write to a particular address is routed in hardware to a particular port or register. This can include general-purpose I/O registers which interface to pins on the chip.